# Is there any space which every two distinct points of it can be separated by two neighbourhoods which one of them is open and the other is closed?

Tags: general-topology

In Hausdorff spaces for every two distinct points $x$ and $y$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint ($U \cap V = \emptyset$). I like to know is there any space with the property that I asked in the above question. If you know please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Any Hausdorf space : take $U$ open containing $x$ and $V$ open containing $y$, then $\overline{V}$ in closed disjoint from $U$.

Comment: @achillehui: It's definitely not the same thing as a $T_0$ space. It's even stronger than $T_1$! Notice that the two neighborhoods in the question have to be disjoint.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You're right.

Answer (score 4):

This is in fact equivalent to being Hausdorff. Indeed such a space is clearly Hausdorff by definition (you impose extra condition on the neighborhoods). Reciprocally suppose that $X$ is Hausdorff. Then for any two points $x,y$ there are disjoint neighborhoods $x \in U, y \in V$. Then $U^\circ$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, $\overline{V}$ is a closed neighborhood of $y$, and they are disjoint (because $\overline{V} \subset \overline{X \setminus U} = X \setminus U^\circ$).